# iOS View.layer.border has a white edge

Tags: ios, uiview, quartz-graphics, quartz-core

I am using `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to define the border of my custom view like below:

```
layer.borderColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR.CGColor; <-- BACKGROUND_COLOR is the darkblue UIColor
```

however after I set it and run on device, I can inspect a very thin tiny blurred zigzag'ed white edge around the view surrounding the border. It looks like a rendering issue.

I am wondering if there can be a fix to this problem?

Thank you

-- Edit: add screenshot (may not clear in low brightness monitor) --
[image]

Comment: what is BACKGROUND_COLOR set to? and you might wanna try layer.borderWidth = 0.0; or something and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @user2277872 the background color is a UIColor.  I still want toe border width to be non zero to achieve the above style.

Comment: Little late, but did you ever get around this? I'm having the exact same issue, and must display with cornerRadius

Answer (score 4):

Set border width too..And try once without corner radius

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
view.layer.borderColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR.CgColor;
```

Comment: You may want to set `borderWidth` to 0.5 on for Retina devices

Answer (score 0):

Add a circle mask to the view after you set the layer's `cornerRadius` and `borderWidth`:

```c
// set layers cornerRadius and border
view.layer.cornerRadius = viewWidth / 2.0;
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
view.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
view.layer.borderColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR.CGColor;

// set mask
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds cornerRadius:view.layer.cornerRadius];
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = path.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = mask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is still open, I have added a tested and working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506436/5576636). see if it helps.